# Минимальная суммарная стоимость билетов

Tags: python

Как можно решить следующую задачу, нужен ли для этого полный перебор или рекурсия? Ниже прикрепляю неудачный код.

**n** людей едет в метро. Известно, что каждому нужно будет совершить **m** поездок.
В метро есть три типа билетов:

- билет на одну поездку, который стоит **a** рублей.
- безлимитный билет на одного человека который стоит **b** рублей.
- групповой безлимитный билет на **k** людей который стоит **c** рублей.

Формат входных данных:

- первый ряд имеет 3 целых числа **n**, **m** и **k** ( 1 ≤ **n**, **m**, **k** ≤ 1000)
- второй ряд имеет 3 целых числа **a**, **b** и **c** (1 ≤ **a**, **b**, **c** ≤ 1000)

Формат выходных данных:
выведите единственное целое число — минимальную суммарную стоимость билетов.

Пример:

```
входные данные
7 4 5
2 7 20
выходные данные
34
```

Неудачный код:

```
n,m,k = 7,4,5
a,b,c = 2,7,20
 
cost_1 = a
cost_2 = b/m
cost_3 = (c/m)/k
 
costs = {"cost_1": cost_1, "cost_2": cost_2, "cost_3": cost_3}
 
min_cost = None
ticket = ''
for key in costs:
    if min_cost is None or costs[key] < min_cost:
        min_cost = costs[key]
        ticket = key
 
 
result = 0
if ticket == "cost_1":
   result = cost_1 * m * n
 
elif ticket == "cost_2":
    result = b * n
 
elif ticket == "cost_3":
    if n % k == 0:
        result = n/k * c
    else:
        temp = n//k
        temp_2 = n - (temp * k)
 
        min_second_cost = None
        second_ticket = ''
        for key in costs:
            if key == ticket:
                continue
            else:
                min_second_cost = costs[key]
                second_ticket = key
 
 
        temp_result = 0
        if second_ticket == "cost_1":
            temp_result = cost_1 * m * temp_2
        elif second_ticket == "cost_2":
            temp_result = b * temp_2
 
        result = temp_result + temp * k
 
print(result)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def foo(n, m, k, a, b, c):
    cost0 = n * m * a
    cost1 = n * b
    cost2 = n // k * c
    print(cost0, cost1, cost2)
    if cost2 != 0:
        cost2 += foo(n % k, m, k, a, b, c)
    else:
        return min(cost0, cost1)
    return min(cost0, cost1, cost2)
```